# Trying to download blob from Azure Storage and getting corrupted file once download completes, why?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, azure-blob-storage

I am trying below code to download a blob (`zip` file) from azure storage account. Programs execution works, but when download completes, the zip file is in corrupted form and not able to extract.

What could be the reason?

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        int processorCount = Environment.ProcessorCount;
        Console.WriteLine($"Total number of processors: {processorCount}");

        string connectionString = "YourConnectionString";
        string containerName = "YourContainerName";
        string blobName = "file.zip";
        string downloadPath = "C:\\TEMP";

        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

        BlobProperties properties = await blobClient.GetPropertiesAsync();
        long fileSize = properties.ContentLength;

        int bufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; // 1 MB buffer size

        long downloadedBytes = 0;
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(downloadPath, blobName)))
        {
            var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, processorCount).Select(async i =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    long startOffset, endOffset;
                    lock (blobClient)
                    {
                        startOffset = downloadedBytes;
                        endOffset = Math.Min(startOffset + bufferSize - 1, fileSize - 1);
                        downloadedBytes = endOffset + 1;
                    }

                    if (startOffset >= fileSize)
                        break;

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[endOffset - startOffset + 1];
                    BlobDownloadInfo blobDownloadInfo = await blobClient.DownloadAsync(new HttpRange(startOffset, endOffset));
                    await blobDownloadInfo.Content.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
            });

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Download completed.");
        Console.WriteLine($"Total time taken: {stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds:F2} seconds");
    }
}
```

Comment: if understood the app flow correctly, async tasks are not guaranteed to finish in the order you created them, which may result  in writing 3rd part of the file earlier than the 2nd, for exmaple

Comment: anyway to correct it @YehorAndrosov

Comment: each processor might write to its own file with the index in the name. then after all tasks complete you would read each file and append it to resulting file respecting the order.

Comment: could you please help me with code?

Comment: The problem with the code is that it assumes `ReadAsync` and `WriteAsync` both always read/write the entire buffer.

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to download blob from Azure Storage and getting corrupted file once the download completes, why?

You can use the below-modified code to download the zip file with parallel processing.

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Azure;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        int processorCount = 8;
        Console.WriteLine($"Total number of processors: {processorCount}");

        string connectionString = "Your-connection-string";
        string containerName = "test"; //conatiner name
        string blobName = "Poppins.zip"; //blobname
        string downloadPath = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\folder1"; //loaclpath

        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

        BlobProperties properties = await blobClient.GetPropertiesAsync();
        long fileSize = properties.ContentLength;

        int bufferSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024; // 4 MB buffer size

        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        try
        {
            var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, processorCount).Select(async i =>
            {
                long startOffset = i * bufferSize;
                long endOffset = Math.Min(startOffset + bufferSize - 1, fileSize - 1);

                if (startOffset >= fileSize)
                    return; // Skip this processor if it's beyond the blob's size

                string tempFilePath = Path.Combine(downloadPath, $"{i}_{blobName}");
                using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(tempFilePath))
                {
                    BlobDownloadInfo blobDownloadInfo = await blobClient.DownloadAsync(new HttpRange(startOffset, endOffset));
                    await blobDownloadInfo.Content.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
            });

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

            using (FileStream finalFileStream = File.Create(Path.Combine(downloadPath, blobName)))
            {
                foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, processorCount))
                {
                    string tempFilePath = Path.Combine(downloadPath, $"{i}_{blobName}");
                    if (File.Exists(tempFilePath))
                    {
                        using (FileStream tempFileStream = File.OpenRead(tempFilePath))
                        {
                            await tempFileStream.CopyToAsync(finalFileStream);
                        }
                        File.Delete(tempFilePath);
                    }
                }
            }

            stopwatch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("Download completed.");
            Console.WriteLine($"Total time taken: {stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds:F2} seconds");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

According to its index, each processor in this modified code writes its part of the file to a different temporary file. When every job is completed, the code runs over the temporary files, reads their contents in the order indicated by their indices, and adds the data to the main file.

**Output:**

```
Total number of processors: 8
Download completed.
Total time taken: 26.03 seconds
```

[image]

**Downloaded Zip file:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Download a blob with .NET - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-download#specify-data-transfer-options-on-download)

Comment: Thanks for your effort here. I tried your code, but my resultant blob zip file is more than actual size, hence corrupted. Looks like in your case it's working.

Comment: How much size is your zip file in MB? and also try with buffer size `8*1024*1024`.

Comment: I am trying to download around 21MB file

Comment: I have posted my version, please check and let me know.

Comment: I tried your code with a 10 MB file it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solve this with below code. Still need suggestion for improvement, if any.

```
 class Program
{
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    int processorCount = Environment.ProcessorCount;
    Console.WriteLine($"Total number of processors: {processorCount}");

    string connectionString = "Your-connection-string";
    string containerName = "test";
    string blobName = "Poppins.zip";
    string downloadPath = "C:\\Temp";

    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
    BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
    BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

    BlobProperties properties = await blobClient.GetPropertiesAsync();
    long fileSize = properties.ContentLength;

    int bufferSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024; // 4 MB buffer size
    int totalChunks = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)fileSize / bufferSize);

    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    try
    {
        var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, processorCount).Select(async processorIndex =>
        {
            for (int chunkIndex = processorIndex; chunkIndex < totalChunks; chunkIndex += processorCount)
            {
                long startOffset = chunkIndex * bufferSize;
                long remainingBytes = fileSize - startOffset;
                long chunkSize = Math.Min(bufferSize, remainingBytes);

                string tempFilePath = Path.Combine(downloadPath, $"{chunkIndex}_{blobName}");
                using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(tempFilePath))
                {
                    BlobDownloadInfo blobDownloadInfo = await blobClient.DownloadAsync(new HttpRange(startOffset, chunkSize));
                    await blobDownloadInfo.Content.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
            }
        });

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        using (FileStream finalFileStream = File.Create(Path.Combine(downloadPath, blobName)))
        {
            foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, totalChunks))
            {
                string tempFilePath = Path.Combine(downloadPath, $"{i}_{blobName}");
                if (File.Exists(tempFilePath))
                {
                    using (FileStream tempFileStream = File.OpenRead(tempFilePath))
                    {
                        await tempFileStream.CopyToAsync(finalFileStream);
                    }
                    File.Delete(tempFilePath);
                }
            }
        }

        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Download completed.");
        Console.WriteLine($"Total time taken: {stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds:F2} seconds");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I can't accept my own anwer